# Bootstrap 4, how to get responsive height on SPA with "no scroll"?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am very new to responsive website design (well front end development in general) and I am trying to create a basic little angular chat application, using bootstrap, designing with responsiveness in mind the whole way. I am however running into a lot of issues when I start nesting flex boxes, and I think I just don't fully understand it. Ideally these are my views when on a larger device and smaller.

**Large**:

[image: fullscreen]

**Small** device (note I have not done anything to make the settings change to a button):

[image: small device]

And here is the reality that I get when using h-100 (I don't see any built in responsive classes for height, but I could be totally wrong):

[image: actual]

I *think* I understand the issue, I am using h-100 with col-12 and so the left side takes up all the room, and the right side is shunted off the page. I have tried getting this same look with flex-fill and flex-grow-1, but they seem to do nothing to the actual document. Here is my code:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContent">
    <div class="row h-100 flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 flex-fill">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 justify-content-between">
          <div>
              <app-channels></app-channels>
          </div>
          <div>
              <app-settings></app-settings>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
        <app-messages></app-messages>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(app-messages also uses h-100 to fill the screen)

custom scss:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Is there a way I can get this content to switch between the views that I have posted above with purely flexbox instead of using h-100? Or are there responsive classes like, for example, h-sm-100 so that it only uses 100% height on small and above?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for height, you may have to take matter in your own hands... which is not that complex as you can see in [this Angular demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-px8lwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

This following code helps produce what you require..

**CSS** part:

```
.outsideDiv{ overflow-y:hidden;}
.app-header { height:10vh; background:#000; color:#fff;}
.myHeight{  background: lightgray; }
.mySection{padding:0; }

.app-messages {  background: #c7b6c7;}
.createMessage{background: lightyellow; margin: 1%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 98%; }
.app-settings {  background:blue; }
.app-channels {  background:#b3fbfb;}

@media SCREEN AND (min-width: 768px){
  .myHeight{ height:90vh;  }
  .app-channels { height: 80%; }
  .app-messages { height: 100%; }
  .app-settings { height: 20%;  }
}
@media SCREEN AND (max-width: 767px){
  .myHeight{ height:auto;  }
  .myHeightSection1 { height:20vh;}
  .myHeightSection2 { height:70vh;}
  .app-channels { height: 100% }
  .app-messages { height: 100%; }
  .app-settings { height: 5%;  width:20%; position:fixed; right:0; bottom:0; }
}
```

**HTML** part:

```
<div class='outsideDiv'>

    <div class="app-header">
        <app-header>
        </app-header>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="mainContent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-flex flex-column mySection">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 justify-content-between order-last">
                    <div class='myHeight myHeightSection1'>
                        <div class="app-channels">
                            <app-channels></app-channels>
                        </div>
                        <div class="app-settings">
                            <app-settings></app-settings>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-12 order-first order-lg-2 order-md-2 mySection">
                <div class='myHeight myHeightSection2'>
                    <div class="app-messages">
                        <app-messages></app-messages>
                        <div class='createMessage'>Create Message</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```